# Letter options in menu stated as undeclared in C program

Tags: c, variables, initialization, char

I think my problem is something simple, but I'm not seeing it. I'm new to programming in C and this is an effort to see what I've absorbed, bit by bit. I think I must have not properly defined my char variable "dopt". Hope you can help. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int dbref();
int aart();
int wgame();
int calc();
int txtoc();

int amin()

{
char dopt;
printf("What should this program have the options of doing?\n");
printf("A) Reference a database?\n");
printf("B) Print ascii art?\n");
printf("C) Make a noun, pronoun, object, verb word game?\n");
printf("D) Being a calculator?\n");
printf("E) creating a text file and save it as a .c file?\n");
printf("F) or should it just terminate?\n");
scanf("%c", &dopt);
if (dopt == a || A)
    { dbref();}
if (dopt== b || B)
     { aart();}
if ( dopt==c || C)
    { wgame();}
if ( dopt==d || D)
     { calc();}
if ( dopt==e || E)
    { txtoc();}
if (  dopt==f || F)
    { return 0;}
return 1;
}

dbref()
{
printf("reference A correct");
return 2;
}

aart()
{
printf("reference B correct");
return 3;

}

wgame()
{
printf("reference C correct");
return 4;

}

calc()
{
printf("reference D correct");
return 5;

}

txtoc()
{
printf("reference E correct");
 return 6;

}
```

As a sidenote, the printf routines in the functions are just to verify that the menu is flowing correctly.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please mark it as such.

Comment: is the function name `amin` or `main` ?

Comment: Nope, this isn't homework. It's called learning for fun.

Comment: BTW=> Thanks for catching that type-o. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is not the same as `'a'`

- `a` is an identifier
- `'a'` is a character

You want to match that if the contents of the char variable `dopt` is any of the characters. So you need to compare the ASCII values of the characters, which can be found by placing the character within a single quotes.

Therefore

```
if (dopt == a || A)
   { dbref();}
```

`a` and `A` are treated as two separate variables (names), which are not declared (at least locally) .

Thus it should be

```
if (dopt == 'a' || 'A')
    { dbref();}
```

Here `'a'` and `'A'` are character constants and not variable names.

**BUT** `'a'` || `'A'` is always 1 because `||` is logical OR operator. Therefore  `dopt` will always be false (almost). But if you want to make the effect that if `dopt` is either `'a'` or `'A'` then call `dbref ()` then you need to do the following:

```
if ((dopt == 'a') || (dopt == 'A'))
    { dbref();}
```

or also

```
if (toupper (dopt) == 'A') // similar with tolower ()
    { dbref();}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew that it was something small. I learned from this too. Love to learn! Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 4):

Code like this:

```
if (dopt == a || A)
```

should be written something like this:

```
if (dopt == 'a' || dopt == 'A')
```

because `a` would be the name of a variable or function (which doesn't exist), and `'a'` is a *character literal*.

Alternatively, you could consider a `switch` block:

```
switch (dopt)
{
case 'a':
case 'A':
    dbref();
    break;
case 'b':
case 'B':
    aart();
    break;
/* etc. */
default:
    fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognised option!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing `dopt == a || A` does not work in C. What you want is

```
dopt == 'a' || dopt == 'A'
```

In C, you have to enclose character literals with `'` (otherwise they are interpreted as variables). You also can't combine the logical or, but have to type in the `dopt ==` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to quote your letters in the option check, otherwise they're treated as variables, and will fail to compile because they don't exist.